# how to update multiple rows in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update multiple rows but not all the rows. 
Say I have more than 1000 entries. And I want to change country of only 5 entries.

```
Sl.No. |  Name  |  Country  | Occupation 
-------+--------+-----------+-----------
  22   | Robin  |   USA     |  Dancer 
  36   | Akash  |  India    |  Dancer  
  98   | David  |    UK     |  Dancer 
 502   |  Raj   | Australia |  Dancer 
 652   |  Bob   |   USA     |  Dancer
```

I want to change it to:

```
Sl.No. |  Name  |  Country  | Occupation    
-------+--------+-----------+-----------
  22   | Robin  |   Canada  |  Dancer 
  36   | Akash  |   Nepal   |  Dancer   
  98   | David  |   USA     |  Dancer 
 502   |  Raj   |   Kong    |  Dancer 
 652   |  Bob   |   China   |  Dancer
```

My php code to fetch data is:

```
<form method="post" action"">
<table>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $country=$_POST['country'];
 mysql_query("update regis set country='".$country."' where name='".$b['name']."'");
}
$a=mysql_query("select * from regis where occupation='Dancer'");
while($b=mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{ $country=$b['country'];?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $b['slno'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $b['name'] ?></td>
<td> <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $country ?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $b['occupation'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: So you are using MySQL api with php7 ? It yes than I am afraid you are reading some obsolete books or article

Comment: Can you show your request data arrays  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get error issue just `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at starting of code. You will get your answer auto.

Their is a simple syntax error foe upload . Just change update query line : e.g

```
mysql_query("update regis set country='".$country."' where name='".$b['name']."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a single quote on this line:

```
mysql_query("update regis set country='".$country."' where name='".$b['name']");
```

Should be:

```
mysql_query("update regis set country='".$country."' where name='".$b['name']"'");
```

Please provide more details about error and print variables content.

Note: use mysqli or PDO instead of deprecated mysql

Comment: Error details lol, op doesn't even aware about obsolete api, IMO it's just terrible code with obsolete  sal injection vulnerability,

Comment: suggest to use php `error_reporting()` for development mode.

Comment: I think you really need to look up PDO, mysql_query() is not ideal for PHP these days - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @CarlCasbolt this is answer not question, suggesting wrong person

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada this is not a forum. And you are potentially doing sql injection. We don't even know how `$b` got into existence. I wouldn't be going low with a snippy comment back to someone